# capybara check input type (fill_in vs check vs select)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, cucumber, capybara

I've got method that fills forms for me with capybara.

After getting some default params from `FactoryGirl` i'm looping tis way:

```
form_attributes.each do |field, value|
    if value == false
      value == true ? check("#{model}_#{field}") : uncheck("#{model}_#{field}")
    elsif try(:select,value, from: "#{model}_#{field}")
      select value, from: "#{model}_#{field}"
    elsif try(:fill_in, "#{model}_#{field}", with: value)
      fill_in "#{model}_#{field}", with: value
    else
      raise Capybara::ElementNotFound
    end
end
```

Unfortunately `try(:select,value, from: "#{model}_#{field}")` will raise error `Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find select box` ...

How to tell capybara to  `check` when element is checkbot and select when element is `<select>`?

Here is some sample of `form_attributes`:

```
{:attitude=>"happy",
 :feedback_date=>2014-08-19 15:35:14 +0200,
 :feedback_action=>"Refund",
 :feedback_details=>"....",
 :approved=>"true"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `#{model}_#{field}` is always the same property (ie id, name or label), you could:

1. Find the element
2. Inspect the element to determine its type
3. Call the appropriate method to input the field

The following codes assumes that `#{model}_#{field}` is the id of an element:

```
form_attributes.each do |field, value|
  e = find("##{model}_#{field}")
  if e.tag_name == 'select'
    e.select(value)
  elsif e.tag_name == 'input' && e['type'] == 'checkbox'
    # Assumes that value is true or false (not a String)
    e.set(value)
  else
    # Assumes e is a text field
    e.set(value)
  end
end
```

In this code, we check the element's tag_name and type attribute if required. As there are many ways that an input tag could be a text field, it is assumed that anything that is not a select list or checkbox must be a text field. You would need to expand the if-else statement if you also want to handle radio buttons, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use the `has_selector?` method in the elsif. It returns a boolean indicating whether or not it's visible within the page. Here's [a link](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Matchers#has_selector%3F-instance_method) the documentation to the page.

TL;DR:

```
page.has_selector?('p#foo')
page.has_selector?('li', :text => 'Horse', :visible => true)
```

Comment: the problem is that it is always visible but you can't fill_in checkbox or select text_field...

Comment: Ah. I thought that the error that was being raised was in the if (statement) elsif (statement) and NOT within the body of the method. @FilipBartuzi, you could try taking a rescue approach, too.